# Sed command to display

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

there is a variable defined in one of the unix profile as

```
sync="/aBCDEDF=="; export sync
sync1="hikjl=="; export sync1
```

and I want the output to be displayed as

```
sync=/aBCDEDF==
sync1=hikjl==
```

how can I display using sed command?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much point using `sed` for this; you can just write:

```
printf 'sync=%s\n' "$sync"
printf 'sync1=%s\n' "$sync1"
```

or:

```
echo "sync=$sync"
echo "sync1=$sync1"
```

(The two are usually equivalent, but the version with `printf` is more portable, due to vagaries in the handling of backslashes by different `echo` implementations.)

Comment: It also can be done with one printf instead of two: `printf 'sync=%s\nsync1=%s' "$sync" "$sync1"`; and even simpler is `printf 'sync=/aBCDEDF==\nsync1=hikjl=='`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file, named `infile` looks like what you showed, the following will do it:

```
sed 's/\([^;]*\);.*/\1/
s/\"//g' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job also

```
set | egrep 'sync1{0,1}='
# or
set | egrep '(sync|sync1)='
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"([^"]*).*/\1/' file
```